# Snowflake UDF calling "Show Shares" function

Tags: share, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to issue a "Show Shares" function call in either a FUNCTION or PROCEDURE in Snowflake? Since there isn't a metadata object in the Informational schema to query information about shares we are looking for a way to create a UDF to obtain this metadata and act on the results.

When attempting to execute the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_share_metadata()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$
    var x=snowflake.execute( { sqlText: "SHOW SHARES" } );
$$
;
call get_share_metadata();
```

The following error is returned:
*Execution error in store procedure GET_SHARE_METADATA: Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'SHOW SHARE'. At Snowflake.execute, line 2 position 20*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute a `SHOW ....` command inside of a stored procedure ***ONLY*** if the procedure is setup to be EXECUTE AS CALLER.

When executing as caller, the role executing the procedure *must* have privileges to execute the commands within the procedure.

**Examples:**

- `SHOW SHARES` is only accessible to the ACCOUNTADMIN role (technically any role can run the command successfully but results are limited to only the accountadmin).
- `SHOW USERS` is only able to be successfully executed with any role that has the MANAGE GRANTS privilege on the account.

**Documentation:**

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-owners-rights-stored-procedures

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about function vs. stored procedure for this, but depending on what you're trying to do, have you looked into just using RESULT_SCAN?

```
SHOW SHARES;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(last_query_id()));
```

Comment: This will work in the snowflake GUI but the command 'SHOW SHARES' is not vaild in the context of a stored procedure (either a FUNCTION or UDF).

Comment: It works in the context of a lot of things, but your use-case hasn't been spelled out in your post.  What is the reason you need it to be in a stored procedure or function?

Comment: We are building a CI/CD pipeline and as part of the validation step we verify the action completed as expected. The CI/CD pipeline needs to have a statement returning success or failure. The concept of multiple statements being run together need to be encapsulated within a procedure. The concept of "last_query_id" isn't guaranteed in a sequence.

Comment: It would be nice if the SHARE information was available in the Information schema metadata.

Comment: Depending on what connector type you are using in your CI/CD pipeline tool, you could execute the SHOW SHARES command, capture the query_id of that statement, and then use the query_id to execute the result_scan() statement.  I've done this in applications before.  I realize it'd be easier if it was available in information schema.

Comment: Also, have you attempted to use SHOW SHARES and a RESULT_SCAN within a JavaScript UDTF?  Your example is leveraging a stored procedure.  If so, does it produce the same error as the SP?